# Should we consider two sets to be similar if their rows contain the same hashes but in different order?

Tags: machine-learning, minhash

Suppose we have minhash signatures for two sets and we want to calculate the Jaccard similarity of the two sets. We have:

`-> S1    S2`

`h1  0     1`

`h2  1     2`

`h3  2     0`

`h4  3     3`

S1 and S2 have the same signatures in different orders. Is the Jaccard similarity 1/8 or 1(approximately)?

Answer (score 0):

These are **different hash functions**, thus `h2(S1) == h1(S2)` means nothing. There is no sense in comparing values of different hashings. So to directly answer - similarity here is 0  (no collisions), so not 1/8 nor 1.

Comment: Makes sense. But, h4(S1) == h4(S2), thats one collision right?